# Does this series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2k+1}}{k^{2}+4k +1}$$
I use the comparison then this series converges.

Comment: So why do you post ?

Answer (score 1):

$0 \leq \frac {\sqrt {2k+1}} {k^{2}+4k+1} \leq \frac {\sqrt {2k+2k}} {k^{2}}=\frac { 2 } {k^{3/2}}$ and $\sum \frac {2 } {k^{3/2}}  <\infty$.